# Get Time US to calculate signature Amazon

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, timezone, locale

I see in . Net have FindSystemTimeZoneById which can get DateTime from any country, but I can't use it in wp7.  I use service of Amazon, if my device set wrong time, I can't calculate signature to call services amazon. Any body here can help me get time any country , ex : US. Thanks

Comment: Is it possible to send Amazon a UTC time stamp?  If so, it is pretty to get this value in .NET.

Answer (score 0):

Currently I think it's pretty hard to do in Windows Phone 7.

Easiest is to get the information form a webservice like this

http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html#timezone